# Writing numbers into a file by column

Tags: matlab

I would like to use MATLAB to write two vectors of numbers into a file and obtain a result like that:

```
  0 ; [    0]
  1 ; [    1]
  2 ; [    2]
  3 ; [    3]
 ...; [  ...]
```

I tried and obtained that code:

```
h=[0:1:100];

a=[0:1:100];

formatSpec = '%3d ; [%5d]\r\n';

fileID = fopen('Write_in_file.txt', 'w');

fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,h,a)
```

Unfortunately, here's the result of my code :

```
  0 ; [    1]
  2 ; [    3]
  4 ; [    5]
  6 ; [    7]
```

Could you help me to get the result that I want? I don't know how to do that actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate `a` and `h` into one array. Otherwise `fprintf` will first go through all numbers of `h`, and then through all numbers of `a`. As MATLAB takes the values column-wise, you need to make sure that the vector looks like this:

```
0    1    2    3    ...
0    1    2    3    ...
```

which can be done with `[h;a]`. So, just call

```
h=[0:1:100];
a=[0:1:100];
formatSpec = '%3d ; [%5d]\r\n';

fileID = fopen('Write_in_file.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,[h;a])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that quick answer ! :)